# How can I paginate sql query result in html page?

Tags: django, paginator

I need to paginate sql query results from my database in html page.

*views.py:*

```
def test(request):
   db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",  # your host, usually localhost
                        user="pc",  # your username
                        passwd="12345678",  # your password
                        db="mc")

   cur = db.cursor()

   cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM hello left join hell on hello.Id=hell.Id ''')

   row = cur.fetchone()
   name = row[1]
   sur = row[2]
   id = row[0]

   context = {"name": name, "sur": sur, "id": id}

   return render(request, 'test.html', context)
```

*test.html:*

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <span style="color:white;font-size:14px">{{ name }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <span style="color:white;font-size:14px">{{ sur }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <span style="color:white;font-size:14px">{{ id }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <span style="color:white;font-size:14px">{{ name }}</span>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Per now yes, it just prints out first values from sql query, I'm working on looping through result.

I stucked in pagination of this. Because results will be more than 1000 and it's good to display 50 per page.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using Django's built in ORM? This would allow you to easily implement pagination.

Comment: yes, using built-in ORM makes pagination easier, but makes working with databases complecated. I need to join 3 tables from second database, no simple joining is in orm, it depends on inspectdb models and for now it's like nuclear physics for me)